# How to add array to fields in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hey I am new to Type script, and I am wonder how would I set ResultsPer and Entries as an array?

```
interface IProps {
    ResultsPer: number;
    Entries: number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IProps {
    ResultsPer: number[];
    Entries: number[];
}
```

Comment: So then how would I pass that into this (it gives me an error) code: return <ResultsPerPage ResultsPer={"10"} Entries={"60"} />;

Comment: @blazing try: `return <ResultsPerPage ResultsPer={[10]} Entries={[60]} />`